# bring back to life old workstation - make workstation great again?

Tags: 18.04, cleanup

at work I inherited an old workstation that runs 18.04. It has been used for a couple of years by different people which have installed/uninstalled/modified god knows what and the result is a truckload of broken packages and a very slow computer. To understand what I mean, it has an Intel® Xeon(R) CPU E5-1620 0 @ 3.60GHz × 8 and 32GB of RAM. However, this poor pc has been abused so bad that it takes a solid 3min to load and maybe 1 minute to open firefox! In addition, there are so many broken packages that i can hardly install anything.

Normally, i would wipe the hdd clean and do a fresh install but here is the problem: the institute i am working for has a strict policy that prevents us from using our personal computer and every PC that uses the ethernet must be bought from the institute and registered in order to be able to use ethernet. That means that once i re-install ubuntu, i wont have access anymore to wired internet. I tried to contact them and tell them to re-configure the mumbo jumbo registering they do but since windows is the preferred OS they really cant bother to help me!

Thus I have 2 options: either clean the OS up wo reinstalling ubuntu or somehow figure out how i can re-register the IP in order to activate the network - which i have no idea how to do!
any help and advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: Without details you can get no detailed help. What packages are broken? Edit your question to provide details.

Comment: @Organic Marble thanks but I am not looking to fix the broken packages, there are layers and layers of misuse there. I am looking for a "soft reinstall" of the OS, or some kind of OS reinstall that will allow me to keep the registering info for the ethernet. if such a solution even exists

Comment: Would it be possible to install Ubuntu alongside the currently installed OS and make the machine dual-boot? Could that be helpful to remain within the policy boundaries of the institute?

Comment: thanks @Joe, yeah it should be fine but then the second partition wont be able to use ethernet as the registration has been done from the partition with the original OS installed...